# How can I mount a Linux ext3 disk image on a Mac in a Linux VM running in VMWare?

Tags: linux, macos, mount, vmware, disk-image

I have a Linux ext3 disk image that I downloaded on my Mac (running macOS Sierra 10.12.3). I also have a Linux VM (Ubuntu 16.04) running in VMWare (Fusion version 8.5.3) on the Mac. I'd like to mount this disk image in the Linux VM.

I've shared the folder on the Mac containing the disk image to the VM, and I can mount it using this command:

```
$ vmhgfs-fuse ".host:/$(vmware-hgfsclient)" ~/Shared
```

But when I try and mount a disk image in this directory, I get a permission denied error:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext3 -o loop ~/Shared/linux-ext3.img /mnt
mount: /home/dave/Shared/linux-ext3.img: failed to setup loop device: Permission denied
```

The same thing happens even if I try and mount it read-only:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext3 -o loop,ro ~/Shared/linux-ext3.img /mnt
mount: /home/dave/Shared/linux-ext3.img: failed to setup loop device: Permission denied
```

The shared directory is mounted read-write:

```
vmhgfs-fuse on /home/dave/Shared type fuse.vmhgfs-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

And the disk image file is readable and writable by all:

```
$ cd ~/Shared/
$ ls -lh linux-ext3.img 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 501 dialout 25G Feb  2 21:01 linux-ext3.img
```

So I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: There are some tricky interactions with `allow_root`/`allow_other` in FUSE and actual root (and I always get confused by them, too). Try `chmod o+rw linux-ext3.img`

Comment: @dirkt: Good call. I tried that, to no avail. Got the same "Permission denied" error.

Comment: Not familiar with `vmhgfs-fuse`: If it doesn't support `chmod`, try anything that would make the image readable to root: `sudo vmhgfs-fuse ...`, or make `root` a member of `dialout`, etc. Or, conversely, try mounting the image read-only.

Comment: @dirkt: Ah! Thanks for the tip about "try anything that would make the image readable to root". I'll write up a proper answer, but it turns out `vmhgfs-fuse` disallows root access, by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, I found out how to avoid mounting anything as root, using `fuse-ext2`. First, that needs to be installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install fuseext2
```

And then mount it like this:

```
$ vmhgfs-fuse ".host:/$(vmware-hgfsclient)" ~/Shared
$ fuse-ext2 ~/Shared/linux-ext3.img ~/mnt/ -o ro
$ ls ~/mnt/
...
```

Note that this does not use `sudo` and it's only visible to your user. To unmount, use:

```
$ fusermount -u ~/mnt
$ fusermount -u ~/Shared
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to a tip by @dirkt above, I was able to determine that `vmhgfs-fuse` disallows root access, by default. From the `vmhgfs-fuse --help` output:

```
    -o allow_other         allow access to other users
    -o allow_root          allow access to root
```

Trying `-o allow_root` initially failed:

```
$ vmhgfs-fuse -o allow_root ".host:/$(vmware-hgfsclient)" ~/Shared
fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf
```

And, sure enough `/etc/fuse.conf` has `user_allow_other` commented out:

```
# Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options.
#user_allow_other
```

But running `vmhgfs-fuse` as root finally worked:

```
$ sudo vmhgfs-fuse -o allow_other ".host:/$(vmware-hgfsclient)" ~/Shared
$ sudo mount -t ext3 -o loop,ro ~/Shared/linux-ext3.img /mnt
$ ls /mnt/
...
```

Note the use of `allow_other` not `allow_root`. Using `sudo` plus `-o allow_root` is redundant, since `vmhgfs-fuse` only grants access to the user that runs the command. However `sudo` alone means *only* `root` can access `~/Shared`, but not your regular user. Using `sudo` plus `-o allow_other` allows root and your regular user (and anyone else) to access `~/Shared`. It might be safer, in a truly shared environment, to enable `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf` so you could use `-o allow_root` and avoid running `vmhgfs-fuse` with `sudo`.

And, for the record, to unmount all of this:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ sudo fusermount -u ~/Shared
```